# XAudio2 filter radian frequency

Tags: filters, frequency

In the documentation for the [XAudio2 filter parameters] it mentions

```
Filter radian frequency calculated as (2*sin(pi*(desired filter cutoff frequency)/sampleRate))
```

Where does this formual come from? What is "Filter radian frequency" and "filter cutoff frequency" and what is the difference. Can someone translate this terminology to mathematics of DFT?

Comment: Duplicate (same user on Stack Overflow): [XAudio2 filter radian frequency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624288/xaudio2-filter-radian-frequency) - question has been satisfactorily answered there so this dupe should probably be deleted ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation where you found this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simply converting analog frequency into digital frequency. For example, if you want a cutoff of 1kHz at a sample rate of 44.1kHz, the corresponding digital frequency is 2*pi*1000/44100 = 0.142... radiants.
In terms of DFT the digital frequency is the $ \omega $ in the $e^{^-j\cdot \omega }$ term of the DFT

Comment: So then where does the sin come in?